# C - Pass structure variable from one function to another function

Tags: c, variables, structure

New coder taking class in C. I'm attempting to write a program that calculates a number for a given date and then uses the number to determine what day of the week the date fell on. Program is unfinished because I am unable to pass user input stored in a structure (struct date udate) from function get_date to function calc_date_number. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    /*Define structure
    ------------------*/
struct date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};


    /*Declare function prototypes
    -----------------------------*/
struct date get_date (struct date);
void calc_date_number (struct date);


void main (void)
{
    struct date   udate, calc_date;
    printf("Welcome to the Date to Day-of-the-Week program.\n\nThe program will give the day of the  
           for any date from 1/1/1900.\n\n");

    get_date (udate);
    calc_date_number (calc_date);
}



    /*Define functions get_date
    ----------------------------*/
struct date get_date (struct date udate)
{
    do
    {
        printf ("Enter the date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
        scanf ("%d/%d/%d", &udate.month, &udate.day, &udate.year);
        if (udate.month < 1 || udate.month > 12)
            printf ("Invalid month. Please re-enter date.\n\n");
        else if (udate.day <1 || udate.day > 31)
            printf ("Invalid day. Please re-enter date.\n\n");
        else if (udate.year < 1900)
            printf ("Invalid year. Please re-enter date.\n\n");
        else if (udate.month ==2 && udate.day == 29 && (udate.year !=0 && (udate.year == 0 || 
                 udate.year % 400 != 0)))
            printf ("Invalid date. Not a leap year. Please re-enter date.\n\n");

    }while (udate.month < 1 || udate.month > 12 || udate.day < 1 || udate.day > 31 || udate.year < 
            1900);

    return udate;

} /*End get_date*/

    /*Define function calc_date_number
    ----------------------------------*/
void calc_date_number (struct date calc_date)
{

    printf("calc_date is %i   %i   %i\n\n", calc_date.month, calc_date.day, calc_date.year);
    long int n;

    if (calc_date.month <= 2)
    {
        calc_date.year = calc_date.year - 1;
        calc_date.month = calc_date.month + 13;
    }
    else
    {
        calc_date.month = calc_date.month + 1;
    }

    n = 1461 * calc_date.year / 4 + 153 * calc_date.month / 5 + calc_date.day;
}/*End function calc_date_number*/
```

Comment: in calc_date_number, you calculate n but then don't do anything with it.

Comment: The function wasn't returning correct results so I stopped writing the program until I could fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version of your program with extra comments to explain.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*Define structure
 *     ------------------*/
struct date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};


/*Declare function prototypes
 *     -----------------------------*/
struct date get_date (struct date);
long int calc_date_number (struct date); /* now return the number */ 

/* use int instead of void */
int main (void)
{
    struct date   udate, calc_date;
    printf("Welcome to the Date to Day-of-the-Week program.\n\nThe program will give the day of the"
    "for any date from 1/1/1900.\n\n");

     calc_date = get_date (udate); /* store the result in calc_date */
     long int n = calc_date_number (calc_date); /* store the result in n */
     printf("calculated date number : %ld\n", n); /* display the value just calculated */
     return 0; /* return code of the program */:
}



/*Define functions get_date
 *     ----------------------------*/
struct date get_date (struct date udate)
{
    do
    {
        printf ("Enter the date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
        scanf ("%d/%d/%d", &udate.month, &udate.day, &udate.year);
        if (udate.month < 1 || udate.month > 12)
            printf ("Invalid month. Please re-enter date.\n\n");
        else if (udate.day <1 || udate.day > 31)
            printf ("Invalid day. Please re-enter date.\n\n");
        else if (udate.year < 1900)
            printf ("Invalid year. Please re-enter date.\n\n");
        else if (udate.month ==2 && udate.day == 29 && (udate.year !=0 && (udate.year == 0 || 
            udate.year % 400 != 0)))
            printf ("Invalid date. Not a leap year. Please re-enter date.\n\n");

    }while (udate.month < 1 || udate.month > 12 || udate.day < 1 || udate.day > 31 || udate.year < 
    1900);

    return udate;

} /*End get_date*/

/*Define function calc_date_number
 *     ----------------------------------*/
long int calc_date_number (struct date calc_date)
{

    printf("calc_date is %i   %i   %i\n\n", calc_date.month, calc_date.day, calc_date.year);
    long int n;

    if (calc_date.month <= 2)
    {
        calc_date.year = calc_date.year - 1;
        calc_date.month = calc_date.month + 13;
    }
    else
    {
        calc_date.month = calc_date.month + 1;
    }

    n = 1461 * calc_date.year / 4 + 153 * calc_date.month / 5 + calc_date.day;
    return n; 
}/*End function calc_date_number*/
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help. So, the added lines in main were necessary to pass info between functions and you corrected one of the prototypes to return the appropriate type of data. Now I can write the last few functions needed to complete the program.